# Using data.table to select rows by distance from another row

Tags: r, data.table

Let's say I have the following data.table.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(x=1:6, y=c(0,0,1,0,0,0))
```

Could I write some command `DT[...]` that selects all the rows within 2 rows of the one in which `y=1`? That is, using proximity to row three, I want to select rows 1-5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option to loop over the position index (`which(y == 1)`) with `sapply`, create a sequence by adding/subtracting 2 to it, get the `unique` elements (in case of overlaps) and subset the rows by using that `i`

```
library(data.table)
DT[unique(sapply(which(y==1), function(i) (i-2):(i + 2)))]
```

-output

```
#   x y
#1: 1 0
#2: 2 0
#3: 3 1
#4: 4 0
#5: 5 0
```

---

If there are negative index, we can subset those

```
i1 <- DT[,unique(sapply(which(y==1), function(i) (i-2):(i + 2)))][,1]
DT[i1[i1 > 0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use rolling operations with different alignment to find if there is `any` value in `y` which has 1 in it with a window size of 3.

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

DT[rollapplyr(y == 1, 3, any, fill = FALSE) | 
     rollapply(y == 1, 3, any, fill = FALSE, align = 'left')]

#   x y
#1: 1 0
#2: 2 0
#3: 3 1
#4: 4 0
#5: 5 0
```

`rollapplyr` is same as `rollapply(...., align = 'right')`